# SVN Commit failed: error 413 Request Entity too large

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am facing the following issue: I have a folder under SVN control and several jar files within it.
The point is that there is a file I cannot commit and I get the mentioned error, but the rest of the jar files were commited with no problem.
And actually, this jar file I cannot commit is the one with lowest size (320kb) and I have commited files with 2.5MB under the same folder.

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should contact the admin or manager of your server for assistance. I recall that a broken antivirus on server or client side can cause this behavior. Don't forget to check your firewall and proxy (if any) and make sure that you use up to date SVN client and server versions.